# Simple_form: Parameter not passing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

I am trying to implement a comment feature for a site. So far, I am able to pass the `movie_id` of the movie I want to comment to, to the page where I create the comment (which is the default scaffold view). After that, I try to pass the `movie_id` to the `create` method of the `comments_controller` but it will not pass. I tried assigning its class (`params[:movie_id].class`) to the `comment` attribute and it says `NilClass`.

My code:

`comments_controller.rb`

```
def create
    @comment = Comment.new
    @comment.comment = params[:comment].values.first
    @comment.user_id = current_user.id
    @comment.movie_id = params[:movie_id]
    #...
end
```

`_form.html.erb` (The one the `new` page renders)

```
<%= simple_form_for(@comment) do |f| %>
    <%= f.error_notification %>

    <div class="form-inputs">
      <%= f.input :comment, label: false, placeholder: 'Your opinion'%>
      <%= f.hidden_field :movie_id, input_html: { value: params[:movie_id] } %>
    </div>

    <div class="form-actions">
      <%= f.button :submit %>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

The `params[:movie_id]` in the `html` file, is actually what I want it to be, I tried adding it as a placeholder and it has the correct value.

This will probably be a stupid mistake but, I am really stuck...

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an error in your html. The hidden field should either use proper rails syntax for a hidden field, or use simple form syntax.

Rails syntax:

```
 <%= f.hidden_field :movie_id, value: params[:movie_id] %>
```

Simple form syntax:

```
 <%= f.input :movie_id, as: :hidden, input_html: { value: params[:movie_id] } %>
```

In controller:

```
@comment.movie_id = params[:comment][:movie_id]
```

Btw, its good form to use strong parameters as follows

```
@comment.movie_id = comment_params[:movie_id]
private
def comment_params
  params.require(:comment).permit(:movie_id, ...(and others..)
end
```

Comment: With the latter, I see the value being set to the field (the field is not hidden even though you specified the `type`) but it still is passing nil.

Comment: corrected syntax above, but when it wasn't hidden, did you see the value in the text field?

Comment: Yep, the value is set correctly. Passing it to the controller though, still shows nil.

Comment: Maaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaan, you are awesome. You can't believe how relieved I am right now. Thank you for your help, you are awesome.

Comment: One more thing. When doing what you suggested in the end of your post, my comment isn't set. I do `@comment.comment = comment_params[:comment]` and this is passed ``"comment"=>{"comment"=>"kkk", "movie_id"=>"1"}``

Answer (score 0):

```
<%= f.hidden_field :movie_id, params[:movie_id] %>
```

This should work?

I would nonetheless do, since in the controller you probably have `@comment = Comment.new` to use the form_for, `@comment.movie_id = params[:movie_id]` in the controller and then use `@comment.movie_id` in the form, just to have it cleaner?

Comment: This throws a ``undefined method `merge' for "1":String`` error